# how to use datalist in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Below i mention datalist sample code using angularjs, 
here my problem is what ever i am typing the text box, in controller add by added every words,in my requirement in datalist selected details only shows in controller,

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser" ng-model="SelectedDoctor" ng-change="LoadSessionData(SelectedDoctor)"> 
<datalist id="browsers" > 
   <option data-ng-repeat="Doctor in DoctorsList" value="{{Doctor.Name}}"   id="doctorList"> </option>
</datalist>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.LoadSessionData(doctorName){ console.log(doctorName) }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the outset, This line seems wrong syntactically,

```
$scope.LoadSessionData(doctorName){ console.log(doctorName) }
```

should change to,

```
$scope.LoadSessionData = function (doctorName){ console.log(doctorName) }
```

Works fine [here](http://jsbin.com/madena/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but my problem is :- what ever i am typing the text box, in controller add by added every words,in my requirement in data-list selected details only shows in controller.

Comment: I didn't get you, could you please frame your question a bit better.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jifibugeke/1/edit?html,js,console,output -- is coming for text changed in the search box, but I want it only for the selected value from the combo box.